# Vue , value is different in Component between data and computed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I find in my code the value showed in data of the component is not the value I want. The code is below:

```
View.component('xxx-item',{
  props:['item'],
  template:`xxxx`,
  computed:{
    computedTest(){
      return this.item.id
    }
  },
  data:function(){
    return{
      test:this.item.id
    }
  }
}
```

And the xxx-item is used for items in a list as below:

```
<xxx-list v-for="item in xxxList" v-bind:item="item"></xxx-list>
```

I think the values of this.test and this.computedTest, which means this.item.id should be same. But they are different actually at some time. Why? what's the difference between the values in data and computed?

The items data are set as below:

```
function loading(){
    axiox.get(xxx)
      .then((res)=>{
        let result = [];
        for(let item of res.xxx.list){
          let obj = {};
          obj.id = item.id;
          .............
          .............
          result.push(obj);
        }
        this.xxxList = result;
      })     
}
```

Comment: Think of props as immutable. You copy the value to your data and never use the prop again unless it changes from the outside. Anything else will drive you insane. (I'm guessing here because you never show how you set `this.item.id`, but I recognize this smell...)

Comment: @ippi when load a list of items, the this.item.id will be set with the id of each data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue will reuse components whenever possible during re-renders. This means if you add, remove or reorder items in `xxxList`, then some of the `<xxx-item>` components will be bound to different items. The computed property `computedTest` will update to reflect this change, but the data property `test` will not change because it was set only once at the component's instantiation.

You need to use [`key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) on `<xxx-item>` to ensure that the same component instance is used for the same item in the array.

e.g.

```vue
<xxx-item v-for="item in xxxList" :key="item.id" :item="item">
```

> When Vue is updating a list of elements rendered with `v-for`, by default it uses an "in-place patch" strategy. If the order of the data items has changed, instead of moving the DOM elements to match the order of the items, Vue will patch each element in-place and make sure it reflects what should be rendered at that particular index.

Answer (score 1):

If the value of the `item` prop has been changed, only the `computedTest` computed property will be updated but your `test` data property will not.

You will need to use `watcher` to enable your `test` data property to be updated every time the `item` prop is changed.

```
watch: {
    item: function(item) {
        this.test = item.id
    } 
}
```

or

```
View.component('xxx-item',{
    props:['item'],
    template:`xxxx`,
    computed:{
        computedTest(){
          return this.item.id
        }
    },
    data:function(){
        return{
            test:this.item.id
        }
    },
    watch: {
        item: function(item) {
            this.test = item.id
        } 
    }
}
```